# Compare groups have same binding keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have samples as below in 2 different tables. I would have to write a sql to compare same source keys are binded together. binding keys in both the tables doesnt match.

In below example, in table 1 there are 3 binding keys 1, 2 & 3. Binding key 1 has 3 members attached to it ABC, XYZ, & QBC. Similarly binding key 2 & 3 each has got 2 source keys attached to them.

In table 2, binding key 99 has same 3 keys attached which are same as table 1(both count and keys are identical) whereas binding key 78 has got the same count as table 1's binding key 2 but they source keys are different. binding key 64 has 1 source key and binding key 65 has 1.

```
table 1:
============================== 
Binding Key|source Key 
1|ABC 
1|XYZ 
1|QBC 
2|xxx 
2|yyy 
3|uuu 
3|ddd

Table 2:
==========================
Binding Key|source Key
99|XYZ
99|QBC
99|ABC
78|xxx
78|QQQ
64|uuu
65|ddd
```

Expected output is to identify groups that doesnt match the count or the source key members.

```
Expected Output:
===========================
xxx 
yyy 
uuu 
ddd
QQQ
```

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Its with the help of listagg function to concatenate strings within the same group and then compare them. example sql is shown below.

```
>  SELECT * FROM   (SELECT grp ,
>     ListAgg( elmnt, ',' ) within GROUP (   ORDER BY pos) AS list   FROM table1   GROUP BY grp   ) table1 WHERE table1.list NOT IN  
> (SELECT ListAgg( elmnt, ',' ) within GROUP (   ORDER BY pos) AS list  
> FROM table2   GROUP BY grp   ) UNION SELECT * FROM   (SELECT grp ,
>     ListAgg( elmnt, ',' ) within GROUP (   ORDER BY pos) AS list   FROM table2   GROUP BY grp   ) table1 WHERE table1.list NOT IN  
> (SELECT ListAgg( elmnt, ',' ) within GROUP (   ORDER BY pos) AS list  
> FROM table1   GROUP BY grp   ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gives desired output:

```
with t1 as ( select row_number() over (partition by grp order by elmnt) pos, 
                    grp, elmnt from table1 ),
     t2 as ( select row_number() over (partition by grp order by elmnt) pos, 
                    grp, elmnt from table2 ),
     tx1 as (select pos, grp grp1, elmnt, 
                    listagg(elmnt, ',') within group (order by pos) 
                                        over (partition by grp) list
               from t1),
     tx2 as (select pos, grp grp2, elmnt, 
                    listagg(elmnt, ',') within group (order by pos) 
                                        over (partition by grp) list
               from t2)
select distinct elmnt 
  from (select * from tx1 full join tx2 using (list, elmnt))
  where grp1 is null or grp2 is null;
```

You could easily change it to show lists, just replace `distinct elmnt` with `distinct list`. The difference between your answer and my query is `listagg` in analytic version and filtered `full join` instead of `union` combined with two `not in` clauses.
First two subqueries (`t1` and `t2`) only adds `pos` column, which you did not present in original question ;-) Probably this can also be done with `minus` operator.

Test data and output:

```
create table table1 (grp number(3), elmnt varchar2(5));
insert into table1 values (1, 'ABC');
insert into table1 values (1, 'XYZ');
insert into table1 values (1, 'QBC');
insert into table1 values (2, 'xxx');
insert into table1 values (2, 'yyy');
insert into table1 values (3, 'uuu');
insert into table1 values (3, 'ddd');

create table table2 (grp number(3), elmnt varchar2(5));
insert into table2 values (99, 'XYZ');
insert into table2 values (99, 'QBC');
insert into table2 values (99, 'ABC');
insert into table2 values (78, 'xxx');
insert into table2 values (78, 'QQQ');
insert into table2 values (64, 'uuu');
insert into table2 values (65, 'ddd');

ELMNT
-----
uuu
QQQ
yyy
ddd
xxx
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. I like your solution, why do you have group sequence generated when order by within group should work the same way?